# Removing the duplicates bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Hi i want a one liner to remove duplicates from the key pairs from two files

5 th and 6 th columns are key value pairs

> > awk '{print $5"\t"$6}' file1 file2 | sort

```
64963661 3 
649963655 3 
649963655 8 
649963658 3 
649963658 3 
649963660 3 
649963660 3 
649963660 3 
649963661 3
```

---

```
awk '{print $5"\t"$6}' file1 file2 | sort  |uniq -d
649963658   3
649963660   3
```

I have to get the following output (**with out the duplicates**.)

```
64963661 3 
649963655 3 
649963655 8  
649963661 3
```

Comment: Why would that be the expected output? Why is `649963660 3` missing? Post an ACTUAL sample input file with 6 or more fields and the expected output from that file so we get a better idea of what you're trying to do.

Comment: The Entry 649963660 3649963660 3 is not included in the output, it is a duplicate key value pair.

Comment: Oh, so you don't just want to remove the subsequent values when they had appeared previously, you want to remove all values when they are duplicated. Got it.

Comment: I have two files with key value pairs and other values and. I need to get the non duplicate key value pairs in sorted order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the whole input line printed (if not, update your question):

```
awk '!seen[$5,$6]++' file1 file2
```

Given your updated question:

```
$ awk '{cnt[$0]++} END{for (rec in cnt) if (cnt[rec] == 1) print rec}' file
649963661 3
649963655 8
64963661 3
649963655 3
```

and if you care about preserving input order:

```
$ awk '!seen[$0]++{recs[++numRecs]=$0} {cnt[$0]++} END{for (recNr=1;recNr<=numRecs;recNr++) if (cnt[recs[recNr]] == 1) print recs[recNr]}' file
64963661 3
649963655 3
649963655 8
649963661 3
```

Comment: Thanks. It's a very common awk idiom, even to the array name `seen`.

Answer (score 1):

Just tell sort to use columns 5 and 6 and to unique:

```
sort -u -k5,6 file1 file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk`:

```
awk '{ ++a[$5, $6]; b[$5, $6] = $0 } END { for (i in a) if (a[i] == 1) print b[i] }' file
```

And in order:

```
awk '{ key = $5 "|" $6 } !a[key]++ { b[key] = $0; keys[i++] = key } END { for (i = 0; i in keys; ++i) { key = keys[i]; if (a[key] == 1) print b[key] } }' file
```